# how to search between two dates and restrict to a particular name

Tags: php, sql, database, where-clause

I am creating a search form that is supposed to search between two dates for a particular users records.

Presently, I can search between two dates using this sql statement

```
SELECT *
FROM `project details` 
WHERE `id`  BETWEEN colname AND colname2
```

But, now I want to make this search restricted to a particular users record

e.g selecting all records for "micheal" between two dates, lets say the column for users was called "username"

How should i edit my SQL statement to achieve such result?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `project details` 
where username = 'micheal'
and date between '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27'
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM `project details` 
where username = 'micheal'
and date >= '2011/02/25' and Date <= '2011/02/27'
```

Both will work. It will fetch records for the user micheal within the date range.

Comment: Between should not be used with dates. Have a look here: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common